# How to check if a char occurs more than once in a string?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
static String encode(String word){
    char[] stringToChar = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    String result = word;
    for (char s : stringToChar) {
        if () {   // if char s occurs more than once in a string word it gets replaced by ')'
            result.replace(s, ')');
        } else { // char s occurs only once in a string word so it gets replaced by '('
            result.replace(s, '(');
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Its from [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/duplicate-encoder/) and I just cant find a way to check if a char occurs more than once in a given string. I know how to replace it (I think I do) but when I tried nested loop to check if its in there I seemed to get some strange outcomes.

Comment: searching for duplicates is basically done by sorting and then checking if any neighbouring elements are the same, perhaps you could do it this way

Comment: The simple solution would be an auxiliary method, say, `charOccursMoreThanOnce(char ch, char[] chars)`. It would keep a count, loop through the char array, return true once the count reaches 2, return false if it never does.

Comment: It’s an aside, but your code doesn’t seem to take into account that your original string may already contain `(` and `)`. When replacing these, you will also replace the new `(` and `)` that you have filled in. I am afraid that you will convert `"aab(()"` to `"(((((("` when it should have been `"))())("`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
// determine if a character has been seen
BitSet previous = new BitSet();
// determine is a character was a duplicate.
BitSet duplicate = new BitSet();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i));
    if (previous.get(ch)) 
        duplicate.set(ch);
    else
        previous.set(ch);
}
// create a new string in a single pass without using replace etc.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i));
    // replace duplicates with ) and non duplicates with (
    sb.append(duplicate.get(ch) ? ')' : '(');
}
```

This is an `O(n)` approach.

The reason you need do this as two passes is that `"(( @"` => `"))(("` note how the `(` is a duplicate in the result and you need to know if `(` or `)` was from the input or the result.

Comment: This can be done using a `HashSet` as  well, right? Any particular reason of using a `BitSet` over a `HashSet`?

Comment: @sonnet BitSet uses as little as 1 bit per value (with some overhead) a HashSet uses around 32 - 48 bytes per Character&Map.Entry&bucket array which is 100-300x more memory.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Could you explain what exactly is the role od Bitset? Im a beginner and havent seen that yet and im not sure what exactly is happening in that piece od code but it definitely seems like the easiest solution to my problem (dont have to import apache and stuff)

Comment: @doublemc a BitSet is a set of bits, in this case one bit per character. The first bitset determines if the character has been seen, the `duplicate` determines if the character was repeated (appeared twice) I suggest stepping through the code in the debugger in your IDE to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Ok, will do when Im home, thanks a lot for helping me out and using std library solution because Im not very familiar with things like maven, gardle and such.

Comment: @doublemc before you worry about those tools, I would make sure you understand how to use the debugger in your IDE.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I understand almost everything in this code but cant find any info on that last line - checked SB documentation and didnt find anything on that ? ')' : '(' . How does it know which one to place where if u only pass duplicate.get(ch) to append method and SB object doesnt havy any contact with previous BitSet?

Comment: @doublemc the `? :` is the Ternary condition operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: There is no point checking the previous bitset at this point as it must always be true for the characters which appeared.

Comment: Now everything is clear - was missing that Ternary condition and couldnt find how its called to check it out. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @doublemc it's tricky to google for unless you know what it is called ;)

Comment: I think I might initialize the bit sets with a capacity of 0x10000 each to avoid extensions underway.

Comment: @OleV.V. true, though that would be a waste if you only have ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to replace anything you can use ready functions for your request.

You can use:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("String text", "char");
```

or

```
int occurance = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf("String text", "char");
```

---

The `StringUtils` class is available in the [Apache Commons Lang 3 Library](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.apache.commons%3Acommons-lang3).

#### Gradle

```groovy
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'
```

#### Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This will not work because the code will be compiled on an online server. The solution OP needs should work using only Java's standard library

Comment: The purpose of the task is to replace duplicates with `)` and non duplicates with `(` so you definitely need to replace or generate a new string.

Comment: Sorry but I havent used gardle/maven yet so have no clue how to use that. Gonna go with a solution available in std library

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a huge flaw in your code.

Instead of

```
result.replace(s, '(');
```

You should write

```
result = result.replace(s, '(');
```

Then, I would recommend to sort the character array first (as suggested in a comment; there are utility methods for doing that). Afterwards, finding and checking a character inside that array should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of occurrences in one line if you are using Apache Commons, like this:

`int count = StringUtils.countMatches(stringTocheckForAs, "A");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you ain't allowed to import Apache Commons in code wars (I'm unaware) or if you don't want to use it, for some reason.

You can initialize an int (or short) array of size 26 (for A to Z) or to 52 (for both capital and small) or to even a bigger size (if input string can contain numbers, symbols, etc too) - initialize each element to value 0 (zero). In the first pass of input string, start counting the number of times each character appeared - set this integer value in the array initialized initially. In the next pass of input string, once you have the counts of each character in the string, if it appears just once, print '(' else print ')', whatever.

This is also O(n) but Peter's solution is better :)

Comment: In the example there is `"(( @"` => `"))(("`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Correct, so maybe an int array of size 128 or 256 or something? Sorry, I'm bad at all this character encoding and all :P Anyway, even while typing out my answer, I knew 'int' or short array ain't needed but unlike you, I was unaware of `BitSet` :)

Comment: `BitSet` has the advantage of sizing as required so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

This could help though a simple duplicate check, doesn't check occurrence count

```
function isIsogram(word) {
    var count = 0;
    var check = ' ';
    if(word == "" || word == null){
        return false;
    }
    var newWord = word.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < newWord.length; i++){
        if(check === newWord.charAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < newWord.length; j++){
            if(newWord.charAt(i) === newWord.charAt(j)){
                count++;
                if(count > 1){
                    check = newWord.charAt(i);
                }

            }

        }
        count = 0;
    }
    return true;
};
```